# ListView with Image lagging, Using Volley NetworkImageView/Aquery/View holders/recycling views

Tags: android, performance, listview, networkimageview

I have done tons of ListViews before with images loading async. But this one is lagging

I get this in the log and then it's gives a small lag

```
09-19 21:13:32.980: I/endeffect(23824): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=1080, getHeight()=561, this=android.widget.ListView{43c94550 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,120-1080,681 #7f0501c1 app:id/sliding_drawer_lv}
```

Here is the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_routes_search, null);

        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mViewHolder.pictureNIV = (NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_image_iv);
        mViewHolder.pictureNIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mViewHolder.titleTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_title_tv);
        mViewHolder.eventTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_event_tv);
        mViewHolder.createdTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_created_tv);
        mViewHolder.createdTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_created_tv);
        App.setFont('m', mViewHolder.titleTv,mViewHolder.eventTv);
        App.setFont('l', mViewHolder.createdTv);

        mViewHolder.extraViewLL= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_extra_ll);
        mViewHolder.contentViewLL = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_content_ll);
        mViewHolder.closeBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_close_btn);
        mViewHolder.favoriteTb = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_extra_fav_tb);
        mViewHolder.shareBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_fav_route_item_extra_share_btn);
        mViewHolder.rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }
    else{
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

and then I set the image with Volleys NetworkImageView, but I also tried Aq with delayed :

```
mViewHolder.pictureNIV.setImageUrl(getItem(position).images.getImageNormal(),App.mVolleyImageLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView was set to wrap_parent in height. This apparently costed the view to recaulate it self.